# Java drawing with turtle

Tags: java

I'm trying to draw axes, triangle, and a square with Turtle in Java.

I have created the method for creating x-, y- axis and another for drawing a triangle. However, when I call them in my main method, they are separately opened through Standard Drawing window.

```
public static void drawAxes(Turtle turtle) {

    Turtle bob = new Turtle();
    bob.penColor ("808080");
    bob.forward(200);
    bob.backward(400);
    bob.forward(200);
    bob.face(90);
    bob.forward(200);
    bob.backward(400);
```

When I call this in main, it creates the x- y- axis.

I have another method for triangle,

```
public static void drawTriangle(Turtle turtle, int sideLength) {

    Turtle bob = new Turtle();
    bob.goTo(-100, 50);
    bob.forward(sideLength);
    bob.face(120);
    bob.forward(sideLength);
    bob.face(240);
    bob.forward(sideLength);
```

I'm not saying both are not creating the axes and triangle, but they are on another windows, which is supposed to be on same window.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    drawAxes(null);
    drawTriangle(null,50);

}
```

This is my main method, and they are created on another window. Plus, I have no idea how it only works with null.

Comment: Why are you creating a new instance of `Turtle` in your draw methods? I assume that's the problem. You'll probably want to have only one instance and have the draw methods be part of that class (for a simple design).

Comment: You mean Turtle in creating drawing triangle method? If I delete `Turtle bob = new Turtle();` in second one, which is triangle, all causes the error.

Comment: No, both methods seem to require a turtle. Have a look at your methods: they take a parameter of type `Turtle` but you pass `null`. Create the turtle in your main and pass the same instance to the methods (they should _not_ create their own instances).